# Is the natural map $L\otimes_F K \to LK$ always surjective?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $L/F$ and $K/F$ be field extensions (not necessarily finite or algebraic or whatever).

Is the natural map $L\otimes_F K \to LK$ given by $x\otimes y \mapsto xy$ necessarily surjective?

I think I can show this to be true if the extensions are finite.

Comment: Where does your proof need the property that the extensions are finite?

Comment: I use the fact that $L=F[a_1,\ldots,a_n]$ for some algebraic elements $a_i.$

Comment: It doesn't seem to me to be the case for transcendental extensions. If you take $F=\mathbb{Q}, L=\mathbb{Q}(x)$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}(y)$ with $x,y$ algebraically independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $LK=\mathbb{Q}(x,y)$, but i don't think you can attain $\frac{1}{x+y}$ by your map.

Comment: I think Keen's example points to the right general answer: $L \otimes_F K$ is isomorphic to the $F$-algebra generated by $L$  and $K$ (in some enclosing superfield), but this can only be expected to be a field if $L$ and $K$ are both algebraic (but not necessarily finite) over $F$.

Comment: See Example 7.9 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod2.pdf, which is Keen's example with a general base field $F$ in place of $\mathbf Q$.

Comment: Also to be rigorous you should embed $L,K$ in a common field to make sense to $LK$ (what is $\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3})\Bbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2)$ ?), and I don't think people use the notation $KL$ when $K(L)/K$ is not algebraic (it suggests the group generated by the $ab,a\in K,b\in L$, same as product of two ideals, so $KL$ is the ring $K[L]$ which is the field $K(L)$ iff it is algebraic over $K$)